# Resource Template for UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm working on a program with multiple `UserControls` that should follow the same visual guidelines, as they will function as `TabPages` of an application to show some data to the user.

Basically, all of the `UserControls` have two columns. In column #1 I have a label describing which value belongs into the actual control and in the second column follows the control (`TextBox`, `DatePicker`, `Checkbox` etc.) for the user to set:

[image: Layout]

When I designed the first of those `UserControls` I ended up with a bunch of `Styles` that I set in the `UserControl`s resources like this, so all Labels would have the same width, right-aligned text and vice versa:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Key"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now, as I'm about to create all other 60+ `UserControls` I would like to avoid to add this exact same code over and over again to every single `UserControl`, just to achieve a consistency in visual style, like same fixed width for labels and so on, as this would be just horrible to maintain (imagine the customer requires all labels just to be 50px less wide...).

Is was wondering if there is any way of setting this formatting stuff once somewhere in the application and then just "import" those settings for my `UserControls` like this:

**Master-file**

```
<Master.Template1>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        ...
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        ...
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        ...
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        ...
    </Style>
</Master.Template1>
```

**Other UCs**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <using Style:Master.Template1/> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I already read some stuff about this `Application.ResourceDictionary`, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with that, as I would prefer not to mess around with the code-behind files.

Or should I create my own Control that **derives** from a `UserControl` that already has all those values set in it's resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new `ResourceDictionary` file to the project. Put your styles in the `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Key"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then add the resource dictionary to your `UserControl.Resources`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just managed to figure that out by myself. :-) But as you put the effort into researching and answering, you'll still get the upvote, as your answer is as correct as can be. I still leave my own answer up, as the article on MSDN contains some useful further information and upcoming users might find it useful to know *how* to add a `ResourceDictionary` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

*Glen Thomas* and myself managed to answer the question at the same time.  I still leave my own answer up, as [the article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx) contains some useful further information and upcoming users might find it useful to know *how* to add a `ResourceDictionary` in the first place.

---

Of course this is possible, and as easy as I hoped: `ResourceDictionarys` were the way to go!

This [article in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx) poked me into the right direction.

I just added a new `ResourceDictionary` to my program

[image]

and put the reference code into it:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Key"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

After that, I was able to "import" the Dictionary into my `UserControl` by replacing the `UserControl.Resources` with this:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And voilà: formatted controls with the ability to choose if to apply the resource "template" or not and a central place to modify the shared values.

Perfect!